# Advice for using FD lenses?

Tags: camera, filming, lenses, adapter

I’m interested in using old FD lenses for filming. Has anyone got any experience with this? What camera did you use? What adapter? Did it work? Were there any issues with focal length, cropping, or flaring? Would appreciate any advice!